# Crash Dump: The remote server returned an error: (412) The append position condition specified was not met

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Our application running on IIS in an Azure Web App has been occasionally crashing. I've monitored the process using the [Crash Diagnoser extension](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2015/12/28/use-crash-diagnoser-site-extension-to-capture-dump-for-intermittent-exception-issues-or-performance-issues-on-azure-web-app/) and picked up a `WebException` thrown from Azure Storage libraries.

We are hosting a .NET 4.7, 64 bit web application (with Kestrel) on Azure Web Apps, using the `WindowsAzure.Storage` 8.1.4 libraries.

Judging from the call stack, this doesn't seem to be coming from our code itself (correct me if I'm wrong). We do use the built-in [Azure Web App Diagnostic Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) to save web and applications logs to blob storage - this could be it?

### Exception Information

> In xyz.dmp the assembly instruction at KERNELBASE!RaiseException in
>   D:\Windows\System32\KERNELBASE.dll from Microsoft Corporation has
>   caused a CLR Exception on thread 202 with the following error
>   information:
>
> ```
> Type:   System.Net.WebException 
> Message:   The remote server returned an error: (412) The append position condition specified was not met..
> ```
>
> This exception originated from
>   System_ni!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult).
>
> Please follow up with vendor Microsoft Corporation for problem
>   resolution concerning the following file:
>   D:\Windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_64\System\6ada715406970ca9c23b97933fa5882d\System.ni.dll.

### .NET Call Stack:

```
[[HelperMethodFrame]] 
System_ni!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult)+2db 
[[HelperMethodFrame]] 
System_ni!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult)+1d4 
Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage!Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[[System.Int64, mscorlib]](System.IAsyncResult)+a1 
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)+51 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+162 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+14 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+52 
System_ni!System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)+95 
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)+c7 
System_ni!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()+13a 
System_ni!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(System.Net.CoreResponseData)+1a9 
System_ni!System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult.SetResponses(System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult)+b0 
System_ni!System.Net.Connection.ReadComplete(Int32, System.Net.WebExceptionStatus)+43d 
System_ni!System.Net.Connection.ReadComplete(Int32, System.Net.WebExceptionStatus)+378 
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)+51 
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)+c7 
System_ni!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32, Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)+149 
System_ni!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ReadHeaderCallback(System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)+a8 
System_ni!System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32)+3b 
System_ni!System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32)+27 
System_ni!System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(System.IAsyncResult)+77 
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)+51 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+162 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+14 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+52 
System_ni!System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)+95 
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)+c7 
System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+121 
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+7c 
[[GCFrame]] 
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]
```

### Full Call Stack

```
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+68     0000000`00000001     0000053`ba92b5e8     0000054`0d1e8dc0     a341630`88d97c00    
clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+2aa     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000    
clr!IL_Rethrow+b7     0000002`fffffec0     ffffec8`00000000     0000053`ba92bd98     0000053`ba92bda0    
[[HelperMethodFrame]]     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000    
System_ni!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult)+2db     0000000`00000004     0000053`937a6d00     0000053`937a6d00     00007fc`5805552d    
clr!ExceptionTracker::CallHandler+fd     0000053`d2e8d120     00007fc`5805552d     0000053`ba92da40     0000053`d2e8d1b8    
clr!ExceptionTracker::CallCatchHandler+90     0000053`ba92da40     0000053`ba92bd20     0000053`ba92bac9     0000000`00000001    
clr!ProcessCLRException+30f     0000053`ba92d800     0000053`ba92da40     0000000`00000000     0000053`ba92bc30    
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForUnwind+d     0000000`00000000     00007fc`58055464     0000000`0004e39c     0000000`00000000    
ntdll!RtlUnwindEx+425     0000053`ba92c930     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000    
clr!ClrUnwindEx+40     0000000`00000000     0000053`ba92c930     0000000`00000001     0000000`00000000    
clr!ProcessCLRException+2dc     0000053`ba92d890     0000053`ba92da40     0000000`00000000     0000053`ba92c930    
ntdll!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+d     0000000`00000000     0000053`ba92d890     0000000`0004e39c     00007fc`00000000    
ntdll!RtlDispatchException+392     568ade4`f9a49000     e2514a1`314ab700     0000000`00000001     0000000`00000000    
ntdll!KiUserExceptionDispatch+2e     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000001     0000053`ba92d828     0000000`00000005    
KERNELBASE!RaiseException+68     0000000`00000001     0000053`ba92d758     0000054`0d1e8dc0     00007fc`6f832570    
clr!RaiseTheExceptionInternalOnly+2aa     0000000`00000000     00007fc`00000008     0000000`2bdf0002     0000053`be0b5258    
clr!IL_Throw+10b     0000054`0d009568     0000000`00000001     0000053`ba92da30     0000053`d3f9a920    
[[HelperMethodFrame]]     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000    
System_ni!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(System.IAsyncResult)+1d4     0000054`0d007cd8     0000001`00000002     0000054`0d0095e8     0000000`00000000    
Microsoft_WindowsAzure_Storage!Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[[System.Int64, mscorlib]](System.IAsyncResult)+a1     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000001     0000000`00000000    
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)+51     0000054`0d009568     0000000`00000001     0000053`ba92dd00     00007fc`5a2cc79e    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+162     00007fc`59e40f80     00007fc`59e40f80     0000053`ba92dc40     00007fc`5a2cc70a    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+14     0000000`00000000     00007fc`5a21ab6e     0000053`00000001     0000053`d3fe2740    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+52     0000053`d3fe2740     00007fc`5a223734     0000054`0d00abd0     0000053`ba92ddd0    
System_ni!System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)+95     0000053`d3fe2740     0000054`0d1e7850     0000053`ba92ddd8     0000000`00000000    
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)+c7     0000054`0d009568     00007fc`580754db     0000000`00000000     0000054`0d007cd8    
System_ni!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.ProcessResponse()+13a     0000054`0d007cd8     0000053`d3fe2740     0000054`0d1e7980     0000000`000000fa    
System_ni!System.Net.HttpWebRequest.SetResponse(System.Net.CoreResponseData)+1a9     0000054`0d007cd8     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00001000    
System_ni!System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult.SetResponses(System.Net.ConnectionReturnResult)+b0     0000054`0d1e79b8     0000053`be0b4fb0     0000053`ba92ded0     0000000`00000000    
System_ni!System.Net.Connection.ReadComplete(Int32, System.Net.WebExceptionStatus)+43d     0000054`0d007cd8     0000053`ba92df98     0000053`ba92dfa8     0000053`ba92dfa0    
System_ni!System.Net.Connection.ReadComplete(Int32, System.Net.WebExceptionStatus)+378     0000053`be0b4ea0     0000054`0d1e6d88     0000053`be0e6ef0     00007fc`58061582    
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)+51     0000054`0d009210     0000053`be14fc68     0000053`ba92e020     0000000`00000000    
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)+c7     0000054`0d009210     0000054`0d009270     0000000`00000000     0000053`d3fe3bb8    
System_ni!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ProcessFrameBody(Int32, Byte[], Int32, Int32, System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)+149     0000054`0d1e6bd8     0000053`0000021f     0000053`be0b4fe0     0000053`be14fcb8    
System_ni!System.Net.Security._SslStream.ReadHeaderCallback(System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest)+a8     0000054`0d009270     00007fc`58054b6f     0000054`0d009368     00007fc`5a203190    
System_ni!System.Net.AsyncProtocolRequest.CompleteRequest(Int32)+3b     0000054`0d009270     0000054`0d1e6bd8     0000054`0d0092b0     0000053`be14fcb8    
System_ni!System.Net.FixedSizeReader.CheckCompletionBeforeNextRead(Int32)+27     0000000`00000000     000c32e`2350e352     0000000`00000000     00007fc`580167e6    
System_ni!System.Net.FixedSizeReader.ReadCallback(System.IAsyncResult)+77     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000001     0000000`00000000    
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.Complete(IntPtr)+51     0000054`0d0092b0     00007fc`69af39a8     0000053`ba92e650     00007f5`fef8e000    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+162     00007fc`69af39a8     0000053`ba92df58     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)+14     0000000`00000000     00007fc`5a21ab6e     0000053`ba92e480     0000000`00000000    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)+52     0000054`0d0092b0     00007fc`5d942394     0000000`00000000     00007fc`58018126    
System_ni!System.Net.ContextAwareResult.Complete(IntPtr)+95     00007fc`5a3f07d8     0000054`0d0092b0     0000054`0d0092b0     0000000`00000001    
System_ni!System.Net.LazyAsyncResult.ProtectedInvokeCallback(System.Object, IntPtr)+c7     0000054`0d0092b0     0000053`ba92e508     0000000`00000000     00007fc`69885afb    
System_ni!System.Net.Sockets.BaseOverlappedAsyncResult.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+121     0000053`ba92e5a0     0000054`00000005     0000053`ef05b5e0     0000000`00000000    
mscorlib_ni!System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32, UInt32, System.Threading.NativeOverlapped*)+7c     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000005     0000053`d7b8af48     0000000`00000004    
clr!CallDescrWorkerInternal+83     00007fc`6c22f468     0000000`00004b9c     0000000`00004b9c     0000053`ba92e620    
clr!CallDescrWorkerWithHandler+4e     0000053`ba92e938     0000000`00000000     0000053`ba92e650     0000000`00000000    
clr!DispatchCallSimple+67     0000053`ba92e938     0000053`d7b8af48     0000000`00000005     0000000`00000000    
clr!BindIoCompletionCallBack_Worker+c7     0000000`00000000     00007fc`69962080     0000053`ba92e950     0000053`ba92e8b0    
[[GCFrame]]     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000    
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchInner+39     0000053`ba92e8b0     0000000`ffffffff     0000000`0000013c     00007fc`69429bef    
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchMiddle+6c     0000000`00000000     00007fc`6959e91b     00007fc`69d27650     00007fc`69429ba7    
clr!ManagedThreadBase_DispatchOuter+75     0000000`00000000     0000053`937a6d00     0000053`937a6d00     0000000`00000005    
[[DebuggerU2MCatchHandlerFrame]]     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000    
clr!ManagedThreadBase_FullTransitionWithAD+2f     0000000`00000001     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     00007fc`6943f7f5    
clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStubEx+b9     00007fc`699621c0     0000000`80010000     0000053`937a6d00     0000000`00000001    
clr!BindIoCompletionCallbackStub+9     0000000`00000001     0000000`80010000     0000000`80010000     0000053`937a6d00    
clr!ThreadpoolMgr::CompletionPortThreadStart+5fc     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000001     0000000`00000005    
clr!Thread::intermediateThreadProc+86     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000    
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+1a     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000    
ntdll!RtlUserThreadStart+1d     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000     0000000`00000000
```